# Create a SQL Server User using Powershell

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I've written a powershell script that creates a new sql server database and login, and then sets the database owner to the newly created user. This is successful. However, I get a login failed exception when attempting to login within the same script. If I use SQL Server Management Studio the login works.

Here's the script:

```
$server = new-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server("(local)")
$db = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database($server, 'TestDB')
$db.Create()

$login = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Login("(local)", 'TestUser')
$login.LoginType = 'SqlLogin'
$login.PasswordPolicyEnforced = $false
$login.PasswordExpirationEnabled = $false
$login.Create('Password1')

$server = new-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server("(local)")
$db = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database
$db = $server.Databases.Item('TestDB')
$db.SetOwner('TestUser', $TRUE)
$db.Alter()
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance localhost -Database 'TestDB' -Username 'TestUser' -Password 'Password1' -Query "SELECT * FROM sysusers"
```

I've tried adding a `Start-Sleep` (up to 5mins) to no avail, and I've tried `Restart-Service mssqlserver -Force`, also to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: There should be more information in the exception than just "login failed" - can you add any more text from the exception?

Comment: ERROR: Invoke-Sqlcmd : Login failed for user 'TestUser'.

Comment: That script worked on my local dev instance (w/ minor tweak for a named instance). Do you have access to the SQL Server logs?  If your server is set up to audit failed logins, the logs will contain more detailed information than is returned to the client.  look for error 18456, etc.  Sounds like you have a work-around, but the logs might help if you're still curious.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer to the problem I was encountering, just a work around. The script is being run as part of an automated deployment, the overall scripts are run under the "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" username, so to get around my logging in issue I'm simply using `Integrated Security=true`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your final line should read:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance '(local)' -Database 'TestDB' -Username 'TestUser' -Password 'Password1' -Query "SELECT * FROM sysusers"
```

Notice the use of **'(local)'** rather than **'localhost'**.

Comment: Tried that to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

follow the codes below

```
$SqlServer = "servar.site.com Or server ip with port"
$SqlDBName = "dbName"
$sqlConnection = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection
$sqlConnection.ServerInstance=$SqlServer
$sqlConnection.LoginSecure = $false
$sqlConnection.Login = "userid if you have"
$sqlConnection.Password = "password if is needed to connect to sql server"

Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL 
Server\140\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll"

$server = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server($sqlConnection)

 # get all of the current logins and their types

 $server.Logins |
 Select-Object Name, LoginType, Parent

 # create a new login by prompting for new credentials
$NewLoginCredentials = Get-Credential -Message "Enter credentials for the new login"
$NewLogin = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Login($server, 
$NewLoginCredentials.UserName)
$NewLogin.LoginType = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.LoginType]::SqlLogin
$NewLogin.Create($NewLoginCredentials.Password)

# create a new database user for the newly created login
$NewUser = New-Object 
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.User($server.Databases[$SqlDBName], 
$NewLoginCredentials.UserName)
$NewUser.Login = $NewLoginCredentials.UserName
$NewUser.Create()
$NewUser.AddToRole("db_datareader")
```