# Creating a database using PowerShell and SMO throws an exception

Tags: sql-server, powershell

It is supposed to be straight forward to create a database using SMO with Power Shell.
[Create a SQL Server User using Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19178685/create-a-sql-server-user-using-powershell)
There are many others sources with similar script.

Powershell was launched with admin rights and trying to create a database failed with the following error.
[image]

Also launching Power Shell from Sql Server Managment Studio with any data context and trying to create the database or table failed with the same exception.

This was on a Windows 8.1 OS machine.

Comment: I've seen this when the servername is wrong. Check the value of $server before creating the db. If you are using a default SQL instance you should be able to use "." as the server name.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a work around to this problem.
Here is the code that will not throw an exception and create a database:

$server= new-object Microsoft.Sqlserver.management.smo.server 'Hodentek8\RegencyPark'
 $dbname= "Regalia"
 $db=new-object  Microsoft.Sqlserver.management.smo.Database ($server,$dbname)

$db.Create()

If dbname is defined first and later used in creating the new object the exception is not raised. SQLPS was launched in the server context.